# percent causing NAN XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0

I am attempting to parse a document using XSLT 1.0 for insertion into a database and I am noticing an issue where any time I have a % value it will return as 'NaN' rather than the actual value.  I cannot find anywhere this issue is adressed

Source:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="NaNValues.xsl" ?>
<items>
    <item>10%</item> 
</items>
```

Template:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" method="xml" indent="yes" version="1.0"/>

<xsl:template match="items">
 <xsl:for-each select="item">
  <xsl:call-template name="IsNaN"/>
 </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="IsNaN">
 <MyItem>
   <xsl:variable name="myItem" select="item" />
   <xsl:value-of select="$myItem"/>
 </MyItem>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<MyItem>NaN</MyItem>
```

I have tried the following:

```
substring($myItem,1,2)
substring($myItem,1,3)
concat($myItem,'')
string($myItem)
```

The main question I have is how should be handling the percent symbol in my input file.

Comment: You can use the `translate()` function to remove the `%` and process the value as a number.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how this code can produce NaN. It's not doing any arithmetic, which is where NaN always comes from. When I run it, it produces this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MyItem/>
```

Please check that you are running the code you say you are running, and if it really gives NaN, give us details of how you are running it (e.g. which processor, and how invoked).

The code is clearly nonsense - the template isNaN is called with the "item" element as context node, and it attempts to find the children of the context node named "item", and of course there are no such children. But that should return nothing, not NaN.

Comment: in the actual implementation I am only attempting to select a value from a more complex XML document.  I am not trying to process the value, I am only attempting to display the value.  I am curious if the '%' character which is in the input can be the cause.

Comment: The % character is very likely to be the cause: it will result in a NaN if you attempt to convert the value to a number. But the code you showed wasn't attempting to convert it to a number. So either you showed us the wrong code, or something odd is going on.

Comment: Michael, you are correct, after thinking I'd tried everything I posted this.  The actual implementation used an ancestor-or-self call which looked similar to:  

' ancestor-or-self*/tagname '

 when it should have been 

'ancestor-or-self::*/tagname'

Answer (score 2):

NaN is never equal to anything - even not to itself. So if you have two values that are NaN they won't be equal. You can check this by running this small xslt transformation against any valid xml file:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:value-of select="'3%' = '3%'"/>|<xsl:value-of select="number('3%') = number('3%')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

The result is:

```
true|false
```

number('3%') is trying to convert '3%' to a number which is not valid and results in NaN. So in the second case effectively have NaN = NaN which as you can see is false.

Coming back to your case - it depends on what you want to do with this value. If you try blindly to use it in any mathematical operation (addition, multiplication etc.) the xslt processor will try to convert your value to a number (which is NaN because of the % character) and from this point the result of any mathematical operation will be NaN (which, as we now know) is not equal to anything. 
If you want to treat the value as string and it is for some reason converted to a number first so instead of the value you want you have string you can cast it explicitly by doing string(item). Finally if you just want to check whether the value is a valid number you can use the trick from above and do:

```
<xsl:value-of select="number($item) = $item"/>
```

If the value is not convertible to a number the number($item) returns NaN (which, as we know, is not equal to anything) meaning the item is not a valid value. If the $item can be converted to a number than the other side of '=' will be converted implicitly to a number and both should have the same value which results in returning true

Comment: If you do want the number value, you can use the `translate()` function in order to remove the `%` from the value: `translate('10%','%','')` and can combine that with the @Pawel's answer in order to identify numeric values that happen to have `%`: `<xsl:template match="item/text()[number(translate(.,'%',''))=translate(.,'%','')]">
        <xsl:value-of select="number(translate(.,'%',''))"/>
    </xsl:template>`

Comment: @MadsHansen This is a great solution for my issue.  I apologize for the typos in the initial code, I was just trying to offer code representative of what I was trying to accomplish and obviously didn't proofread it thoroughly.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious problem is that the provided code is calling this template with current node an `item`:

```
<xsl:template name="IsNaN">
 <MyItem>
   <xsl:variable name="myItem" select="item" />
   <xsl:value-of select="$myItem"/>
 </MyItem>
</xsl:template>
```

This attempts to output the string value of the first `item` **child** of the current node -- however in the provided XML document an `item` doesn't have an `item` child itself.

Of course, this doesn't explain why NaN is returned -- any compliant XSLT processor must produce the empty string. I believe that your actual code is different from the one you have shown us and the actual code involves arithmetic operations. In such case the evaluation of the expression attempts to convert the empty string to a number -- and the result of this is NaN.

**Simply rewrite the above template like this**:

```
<xsl:template name="IsNaN">
 <MyItem>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
 </MyItem>
</xsl:template>
```